# Validar si existe un array dentro de un JSON

Tags: javascript, nodejs, jsonarray

Estoy intentando validar si existe un array dentro de un JSON, la idea es poder validar cuando recibo el json que ese campo exista, si no existe entonces tiro el error:

```
{

"id": 113524,
"name": "John",
"Array": [
"name":"Anthony",
"value":"A"
]

}
```

Estoy leyendo el array en una variable:

```
let json = req.body;
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(json);
let jsonValue = JSON.parse(jsonData);
let jsonSpecificValue = jsonValue.Array[0].value;
```

Si quiero validar que venga ese Array en el json intento algo como:

```
if(!jsonValue['Array']){

console.error('Error');

}
```

El error que me está dando es el siguiente:

(node:20056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

El error apunta a la variable jsonSpecificValue.

Como puedo validar que existe ese Array en el JSON ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que req.body retorna esto

```
{
   "id": 113524,
   "name": "John",
   "array": [{
       "name":"Anthony",
       "value":"A"
    }, {
       "name":"Penelope",
       "value":"B"
    }]
}
```

Entonces puedes verificarlo asi

```
let json = req.body;

// No tenemos que verificar si json es un json valido 
// ya que express verifica esto cuando pones el middleware **body-parser**
// parse application/json
// app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Entonces seguimos
const { array } = json;

if (!array || !Array.isArray(array)) {
    return res.status(400).json({
       message: "array es requirido"
    });
}

// Aqui ya sabes que array existed entonces puedes seguir con tu logical 
// Por to pregunta no vi que querias mandar error cuando array esta 
// bacio asi que no chequee en el if arriba

// ... Resto de to codigo

// y terminas mandando la respuesta
// Nota que no ponemos status ya que res.json añada status 200 a la respuesta
return res.json(
   // Tu respuesta cuando todo va bien  
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas en tu código.

**Primero:** el supuesto JSON que estás recibiendo no es válido. Puedes verificarlo [aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

En la clave `Array` del objeto, por lógica, debería haber **un array de objetos JSON**. Por tanto, la estructura correcta sería esta:

```
{
   "id":113524,
   "name":"John",
   "Array":[
      {
         "name":"Anthony",
         "value":"A"
      }
   ]
}
```

NÓTESE las `{}` dentro del array.

**Segundo:** al menos en mi prueba el uso de `JSON.stringify` fastidiaba el objeto. Puedes prescindir de él, aplicando el parse directamente sobre la respuesta. Vamos a probar un código con un objeto correcto y evitando `JSON.stringify`. Así funciona:

```js
//let json = req.body;

//lo ponemos manual, para prueba
let json=`{
"id": 113524,
"name": "John",
"Array": [{
"name":"Anthony",
"value":"A"}
]
}`;

//Esto sobra
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(json);

//Aplicamos el parse directamente sobre json
let jsonValue = JSON.parse(json);
/*
Con este ternario verificamos 
si el array está vacío 
y si la clave value no existe en el json
en ambos casos retornará false
evitando así el undefined
*/
let jsonSpecificValue = (jsonValue.Array && jsonValue.Array.length > 0) ? jsonValue.Array[0].value || false : false;

console.log(jsonSpecificValue);
```

Comment: entiendo. Pero de esa manera me da otro error: (node:4284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). Si quisiera validar si ese Array existe dentro del json podria validarlo de la siguiente manera? if(!jsonSpecificValue)

Comment: @EstebanVarela los errores del tipo `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse` ocurren cuando se está devolviendo un JSON no válido (en ese caso desde el Request). No sé si eres el programador del lado del servidor, si lo eres, debes garantizar de ese lado que se responda **siempre** un JSON válido.Igualmente, para validar del lado del cliente si el array existe, debes implementar una política de manejo de errores donde, si ese dato no existe pongas en la respuesta una clave `error` y verifiques por esa clave. Puedes hacerlo también verificando primero si ...

Comment: ... la clave `Array` existe en la respuesta y luego si ese array no está vacío, pero eso es menos genérico y más complicado que tener tu propia política de manejo de errores, la cual incorporarás a la lógica y coherencia de tu código. Todos los problemas que estás teniendo es por ese motivo, porque estás dejando escapar cosas en la respuesta desde el servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano, solo faltaría la validación de que existe el elemento y no está vacío: `let jsonSpecificValue = (jsonValue.Array && jsonValue.Array.length > 0) ? jsonValue.Array[0].value : false;`

Comment: Gracias @Triby he puesto el control que indicas, y he añadido otro por si no existe una clave `value` en el JSON mediante el operador `||`